# Shader preview window maxing out CPU, blender 3.0

Tags: materials, interface

I have noticed that having the material preview window displayed (the right hand side plane/ cube/ sphere view etc.) causes the CPU to hit 100% use until the shader has been compiled and slows down the whole apps responsiveness(even with a very simple shader setup).
Without the preview window showing the shader compiles with a "normal" CPU load (30 - 70% approx.) depending on shader complexity.
This is with only the GPU chosen as the device to use under system preferences for both CUDA and Optix and in render settings for the project.
Using blender 3.0 with Nvidia RTX2060 Super ( driver 497.29), Windows 11, Intel 8th Gen i5-8400, no 3rd party addons.
Is this particular to my system setup/ app preferences or is it a known issue?

Comment: I've had responsiveness issues with the node editor myself, and while closing the preview pane helps a little, I found that changing the system font in user preferences to a ttf with a smaller file size actually helps a lot more. (I'm commenting instead of answering because it doesn't address the actual issue that you presented.)

Comment: Yes the node editor slows down a lot as well, but the whole app becomes slow like treacle while the preview window updates. It never used to be like that. Will try your font suggestion, thanks for that.